# How does the function sort the nodes?

Tags: integer, nodes, networkx, labeling, digraphs

I have a DiGraph. The nodes have a string label. I want to assign an integer value to each node. The numbering of the nodes from 1, ..., n should be such that the dependencies are taken into consideration. Example:

Let nodes n1, n2, n3 and n4 be given. The dependency is n1->n2, n1-> n3, n2 -> n3 and n3 -> n4. The predecessors should assume a smaller integer value.

n1 = 1

n2 = 2, because n3 has n2 and n1 as predecessors

n3 = 3, n3 cannot be 2 because n2 is another predecessor of n3

n4= 4

I tried it with the function convert_node_labels_to_integers from networkx. I selected ordering ="sorted". However, I did not understand how it is sorted. Do you know a numbering method where I don't have to do any relabelling? Maybe something like inserting an index reference for each node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is called topological sorting. Available in Networkx via the function `nx.topological_sort`. [Documentation here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12357580/di1a). Note that `topological_sort` returns an ordered set of node IDs; you will have to re-label the nodes yourself.

Comment: How can I test whether the sorting has been done in the required order? Can I save this sorted nodes in a list or something else?

Comment: I would validate the function using a few toy examples. You can save the returned node list in any format you desire.